# How to set video dimensions with UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

How do I set the video dimensions that I want to record with, when I use the UIImagePickerController?

I am developing an application that uses the UIImagePickerController with a custom view on top for the controls. When I record I am finding the proportions of the video look 4:3, rather than the 16:4 I am expecting.

When I look at the Apple documentation it provides an [example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html) of the form:

```
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720;
```

The issue is that I can't seem to see how to get the session to be able to set this value, when I use the UIImagePickerController. My Swift 2 based code looks somewhat as follows (slightly edited):

```
cameraController = UIImagePickerController()

if (cameraController != nil) {
    cameraController!.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
    cameraController!.sourceType = .Camera
    cameraController!.cameraCaptureMode = .Video

    cameraController!.allowsEditing = false
    cameraController!.delegate = self
    cameraController!.showsCameraControls = false

    self.recorderOverlayView = (NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("VideoRecorderOverlayView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! VideoRecorderOverlayView)

    if (self.recorderOverlayView != nil) {

        self.recorderOverlayView!.frame = self.view!.frame                
        recorderOverlayView?.delegate = self;

        locationLabel = recorderOverlayView?.viewWithTag(1) as? UILabel

    } else {
        print("view not loaded")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While UIImagePickerController doesn't seem to provide access to the session, it does have a videoQuality property, which seems to be the right place to set this value. In my case:

```
cameraController!.videoQuality = .TypeIFrame1280x720
```